# jquery/ js speed test

Tags: jquery

I'm using lots of jquery/js in my website. I need to test my jquery performance and improve its performance. Is there any tools to monitor the jquery performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firefox's Firebug has some pretty neat plugins for that:

- [YUI slow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)
- [Google Page Speed](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/speed/page-speed/download.html)

Even if these plugins are very handy, you could measure the Javascript performance just with Firebug (Firefox) and the Developer Tools (Chrome).

Comment: Using YUI google scroes a 70(C) and YAHOO, who I belive create the addon, scored only a 75(C)... and i think both of those sites load pretty fast... Is it possable to get an A?

Comment: Neither YSlow nor Page Speed test the actual JavaScript performance.

Comment: @Gumbo: PageSpeed offers the "Profile Deferrable Javascript" option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

[Well explained here](http://addyosmani.com/blog/8-jquery-performance-tips/)

[YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

To calculate your jQuery time in IE you can use

```
var startTime = new Date(); 
jQuery.ready(); 
var endTime = new Date(); 
var difference = endTime - startTime; 
alert("document.ready time: " + difference + " milliseconds");
```

with this code you could get time for jQuery to load

with regards

**Wazzy**

Comment: I like the idea, but do you have any idea why it's telling me it takes 0 milliseconds for the page to load?

Comment: You need to write the code in $(document).ready(function(){  , I think you are

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend free [**DynaTrace AJAX Edition**](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/download/download.aspx).

It is a brilliant performance profiler for IE. It will allow you to see the execution time and number of calls of each javascript method so you can find your bottlenecks easily and quickly.

I've used it to optimize javascript heavy, AJAX-enabled portal (opensocial implementation) and found out ie. nonoptimal jQuery selectors, unnecessary and heavy loops, IE problems with offsetHeight and class attributes.

Here's the full list of [**features**](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/content/feature-tour.aspx).